# $3\tau(K_1$#$K_2)$=$\tau(K_1)\tau(K_2)$

Tags: knot-theory

Suppose we have two knots $K_1$ and $K_2$. Then look to the *connected sum* of $K_1$ and $K_2$ denoted by $K_1\#K_2$ (defined for knots). Suppose $\tau$ is the number of $3$-colourings (definition for knots). I want to prove the formula above, namely: $3\tau(K_1\#K_2)=\tau(K_1)\tau(K_2)$. I read about some proofs with help of $n$-tangles. But i ask myself if there are proofs without such tangles?? Is it possible to come to the solution just with counting??

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** Wirtinger presentation.  The thing about Fox $3$-colorings is that they actually correspond to homomorphisms $\pi_1(S^3-K)\to D_{3}$, where $D_{3}$ is the symmetries of the triangle, and where meridians are sent to flips.  Take a diagram of a connect sum where it is obviously a connect sum (so one can draw a circle bounding the $K_1$ part that intersects $K_1\# K_2$ in exactly two points), and the meridian generators for the two intersected arcs are equal.  Thus, they are sent to the same thing in $D_3$ under any homomorphism, and hence they have the same coloring in any Fox $3$-coloring.  In the following picture, the blue circle demonstrates the connect sum, and the green loops are the meridian generators for the two intersected arcs.

[image: Meridian generators on both strands of connect sum]

The result follows since in the connect sum the two arcs have to be the same color, but individually the knots have no constraint on the color of the arcs.

**Method 2:** Tangles without the tangles.  Jozef Przytycki has a nice argument in [3-coloring and other elementary invariants of knots](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608172).  I'll give a variation on the argument which never uses the word "tangle."  Consider taking $K_1\#K_2$ and and adding an extra unknotted component.  If $K_1\#K_2$ can be $3$-colored, then the new diagram can be $3$-colored in three times the ways since there are no constraints on the new unknot.

[image: Connect sum with extra loop]

The unknot can be isotoped to be under and around $K_1$ in the diagram.  This implies the colors $a$ and $b$ in the diagram are equal, since otherwise $c$ passed under $a$ and $b$ would be a different color from itself.  Therefore, the result follows.

**Method 3:** the Jones polynomial.  Przytycki and Lickorish-Millet proved that the Jones polynomial at the sixth root of unity gives the number of 3-colorings (see https://mathoverflow.net/a/176866).  If you know that the Jones polynomial is multiplicative, then the result follows.

---

I don't know how or if the next one can be finished by a direct argument.

**Method 4:** representation theory of $S_3$. Since $3$-colorings are invariant under permutations of the colors, we could develop a planar algebra (sorry... involves tangles and tensor diagrams).  Let $V$ be the $3$-dimensional permutation representation of $V$, with $e_1,e_2,e_3$ the basis representing the three colors.  We can decompose knots into cups, caps, crossings, and identity strands and replace them with tensor operators on $V$.  With the following replacements

[image: tensor replacements]

the resulting element of $\mathbb{C}$ is an integer -- the number of Fox $3$-colorings.  A tangle gives a map $V^{\otimes n}\to V^{\otimes m}$ that is an intertwiner since each of the pieces of the decomposition are $S_3$ intertwiners.

In a connect sum, each component corresponds to a map $V\to V$.  The trace of the composition of the maps is the number of $3$-colorings of the connect sum.  The claim is that $V\to V$ is a scale multiple of the identity map, which means that the "input strand" and the "output strand" always have to be the same color.

The representation decomposes as $V=T\oplus W$ into irreducible representations, where $T$ is the $1$-dimensional trivial representation spanned by $e_1+e_2+e_3$ and $W$ is the orthogonal complement.  An intertwiner $f:V\to V$ is determined by how it scales $T$ and $W$.

If one could show it has to scale $T$ and $W$ by the same amount, the result would follow.